# Using loops for repetitive songs

Tags: javascript, loops, text, dynamic

dI am trying to use for loop for displaying children song "10 green bottles hanging on the wall". So I am starting loop at 10 and down to 0. The text is supposed to add up and finally the whole songs should be displayed

for i=10 i=0 i--, And the text inside the loop. The numbers should be changing, but the rest should stay the same

```html
   

 <div id="demo"></div>

    <script>
      function favsong() {
        var i;
        var song = "";
        var poem = "green bottles, hanging on a wall";
        var poem1 ="If 1 green bottle were to accidentally fall. There'd be";
        
        for (i=10;i=0;i--) {
          song+=i+poem+"<br>"+i+poem+"<br>"+poem1;  
          if (i==1){
song+="1 green bottle hanging on the wall"+"<br>+"1 green bottle hanging on the wall"
continue
}
        }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = song;
      }
    </script>
```

```
10 green bottles, hanging on a wall,
10 green bottles, hanging on a wall,
If 1 green bottle were to accidentally fall
There'd be 9 green bottles, hanging on the wall
9 green bottles, hanging on a wall,
9 green bottles, hanging on a wall,
If 1 green bottle were to accidentally fall
There'd be 8 green bottles, hanging on the wall
8 green bottles, hanging on a wall,
8 green bottles, hanging on a wall,
If 1 green bottle were to accidentally fall
There'd be 7 green bottles, hanging on the wall
... and so on...
1 green bottles, hanging on a wall,
1 green bottles, hanging on a wall,
If 1 green bottle were to accidentally fall
There'd be 0 green bottles, hanging on the wall
```

Comment: I do not get what is the question, but it seems me that you for loop is wrong. It should be: `for (i = 10; i > 0; i--)`

Comment: what is « tall » ?? it should be « i » instead

Comment: I don't see where you are appending poem.  i do see where you are appending a literal string of "poem".  Looks like a typo

Comment: i started to write an answer, but there are various issues here.  The variable as a literal string is one issue.  Never calling `text1()` is an issue.  There are some spacing issues for the numbers and the text that will need fixing.  And the "# green bottles, hanging on a wall" line is only repeated once after the first iteration

Comment: I thought I was appending a poem in the song+= ... and then by trying to display on the screen within the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your for loop typo to use `i--` in place of `tall`.

Another issue is using `"poem"` and `"poem1 "` in double quotes, that means it's a string so the actual value of song and poem are not used inside for loop.

```js
function text1() {
    var i= 0;
    var song = "";
    var poem = " green bottles, hanging on a wall";
    var poem1 = "if 1 green bottle were to accidentally fall. There'd be "
    
    for (i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
      song += i + poem + "<br>" + i +"" + poem + "<br>" + poem1 + "";  
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = song;
    }
  }
  
  text1();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Displays zero bottles without poem1. Also using template literals for readability.

```
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
  function text1() {

    var i;
    var song = "";
    var poem = "green bottles, hanging on a wall\n";
    var poem1 = "if 1 green bottle were to accidentally fall. There'd be\n"

    for (i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
        song += `${i} ${poem}${i} ${poem}`
        if(i) {song += poem1}
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = song;
 }
</script>
```